# Condition fails in Junit5 & Mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit5

I am trying to write the test case for my application and I cannot get past a condition even after providing what is expected, from what I know.

Here is my test class.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class AppConfigTest {

  @Mock
  @TempDir
  File mockedFile;

  @InjectMocks
  private AppConfig appConfig;

  @Test
  void getData() throws Exception {
    File f = new File("f");
    File[] files = {f};

    lenient().when(mockedFile.listFiles()).thenReturn(files);
    lenient().when(mockedFile.isFile()).thenReturn(true);
    assertNotNull(appConfig.getData());
  }
}
```

My implementation. The test doesn't go past the if condition. The test does not cover the code after the condition as it turns true all the time. I need my test to cover keyMap() in the last line.

```
  private Map<String, String> getData() {
    File[] files = new File(APP_CONST.DIRECTORY).listFiles();
    if (null == files) { // not turning FALSE even after providing mocked "files" array 
      return Collections.emptyMap();
    }
    List<String> keysList = getKeyList(files);
    return keyMap(APP_CONST.DIRECTORY, keysList);
  }
```

Can anyone please tell me how to correct this please? Using SpringBoot/JUnit 5

Comment: I would suggest doing it differently. The problem is the file creation is not abstracted. By providing a FileProvider you can mock the listFiles() by this @TempDir File (without using @Mock) more easily.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `@TempDir`, but is it a common usecase to use it together with `@Mock`? From the docs sounds more like `@TempDir` creates a temporary directory for you and doesn't need to be mocked. Also, when creating a tempdir, my assumption is that it would always be empty. Another thing I can't seem to understand is, why create a temporary dir if you're always listing a specific one - `File(APP_CONST.DIRECTORY)`? What is it that you're trying to achieve here? mock the returned files?

Comment: `File(APP_CONST.DIRECTORY)` is in the class under test and not in the test class. @Tempdir was used to mock a directory for the test

Comment: @continuousLearner I still don't get it though. In you test, you're not doing anything to guarantee that `APP_CONST.DIRECTORY`  exists. The javadoc states that if an io error occurs or the path does not denote a directory `listFiles` returns null. I'm just confused how you  want to guarantee that the `if` is true or false?

Comment: `APP_CONST.DIRECTORY` in reality is a unix path. I am testing in windows. `listFiles ` is not supposed to fail as the directory has been mocked using @TemDir.  I had also tried `File f = new File(mockedFile, "f.txt")` in the test method but upon debugging it, I see that listFiles() returns empty in the method under test. How do you suggest to make `listFile` return values during the test?

Comment: So that's what I mean I don't see how it would work like this. As far as I can tell `TempDir` creates a temporary directory with a random name, but then you access a very specific one - `APP_CONST.DIRECTORY`. in order to make sure you control this, either ensure that the same directory is created in the test and populated with files, or create a new abstraction that provides said directory like greedsin suggests in a comment above. I'm happy to provide an example as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We discussed this in the comments, but in any case, I guess an example is better.

One way you could go about this is to make sure the same folder exists. In the test setup you could simply create it.

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
   new File(APP_CONST.DIRECTORY).mkdirs();
}
```

Now when accessing it in the implementation there will be a directory. You can also inside the test add files to the directory, so it's not empty.

Although this works, it has some issues with setting it up and cleaning it up. A better way is to abstract this from the implementation itself and use some kind of provider for it.

A suggestion would be to create an interface where the real implementation returns the real folder and in tests you can mock this.

```
public interface DirectoryProvider {
   public File someDirectory();
}

public class RealDirectoryProvider implements DirectoryProvider {
   @Override
   public File someDirectory() {
     return new File(APP_CONST.DIRECTORY);
   }
}
```

you can now make the `getData` class depend on this abstraction. You didn't give us the class name, so don't pay attention to that part:

```
public class Data {
   private final DirectoryProvider directoryProvider;

   public Data(DirectoryProvider directoryProvider) {
     this.directoryProvider = directoryProvider;
   }

   private Map<String, String> getData() {
     File[] files = directoryProvider.someDirectory().listFiles();
     if (null == files) { 
       return Collections.emptyMap();
     }
     List<String> keysList = getKeyList(files);
     return keyMap(APP_CONST.DIRECTORY, keysList);
   }
}
```

Now during the test you can just inject your mocked directory/temp dir.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class AppConfigTest {
  @TempDir
  File mockedFile;

  @Mock
  DirectoryProvider directoryProvider;

  @InjectMocks
  private AppConfig appConfig;

  @Test
  void getData() throws Exception {
    lenient().when(directoryProvider.someDirectory()).thenReturn(mockedFile);

    assertNotNull(appConfig.getData());
  }
}
```

You can also add files to the temp dir if you need. This however should be enough to pass the `if` I think.